# Update table more than 1 row

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to ask about query update for SQL Server 2008.

I want to update a table with more than 1 row with query like this.

```
update #temp_cost 
set acct_cd = (
    select acc_no from acc_gltrans 
    where voucher like 'SCS/GR%' 
    and debit_credit > 0
)
where grn_no = (
    select voucher from acc_gltrans 
    where voucher like 'SCS/GR%' 
    and debit_credit > 0
);
```

But got an error like this

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

I hope someone can help me fix this,
Thanks

Comment: I'm no expert, but apparently one of your subquery returned more than 1 value. You can't set your `acct_cd` to multiple values.

Comment: You can use IN operator in place of = operator if you want to update more than one row in sql server.

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to assign a single value with N-Values returned from your sub-query -

```
acct_cd = 
(select acc_no from acc_gltrans where voucher like 'SCS/GR%' 
and debit_credit > 0)
```

In the sub-query you are selecting more than one `acc_no` from `acc_gltrans`,

```
select acc_no from acc_gltrans where voucher like 'SCS/GR%' 
and debit_credit > 0
```

If you just run your sub-query and it returns only 1 row then you can use TOP (1)

```
select TOP (1) acc_no from acc_gltrans where voucher like 'SCS/GR%' 
and debit_credit > 0
```

**But if your sub-query returns more than one row - I suggest you rethink your Logic**

Also you are trying to update more than one row in `#temp_cost` - so instead of `=` use the `IN` operator.

The `IN` operator will allow you to update more than one Row in the `#temp_cost`  Table

so your query will be something like the following.

```
update #temp_cost set 
acct_cd = 
   (select TOP (1) acc_no from acc_gltrans where voucher like 'SCS/GR%' 
       and debit_credit > 0)
where 
  -- HERE USE IN
  grn_no IN 
      (select voucher from acc_gltrans where voucher like 'SCS/GR%' 
      and debit_credit > 0)
```

Comment: umm because i want to update each row with diferent data 
for example in #temp_cost there is 2 grn_no with 0 acct_cd
but in acc_gltrans there is 2 grn_no with 2 acc_no 
i want to update that 0 acct _no with 2 accno from acc_gltrans table

Comment: its just like vlookup in excel that i want to do it 
checking grn_no from #temp_cost and voucher from acc_gltrans if the grn_no and voucher is matching then update acct_cd from #temp_cost with acc_no from acc_gltrans

Answer (score 0):

Here using This

```
UPDATE #temp_cost As temp set 
    temp.acct_cd = A.acc_no
FROM acc_gltrans as A
WHERE A.voucher like 'SCS/GR%' AND A.debit_credit > 0)
```

Hope help